# Order of quotient group in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I'm learning abstract algebra, specifically group theory, and need help with the following problem:

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $n, m  \geq 2$. For every natural number $k$, we denote $\langle k \rangle$ the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ generated by $k$. Show that $|\langle n \rangle / \langle nm \rangle| = m$.

I'm sorry for my lack of effort but I was not able to do much with this one. Is is also unclear to me at the moment why the proposition fails for $m,n = 1$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't fail for $m=1$ or $n=1$.

Comment: What makes you think the proposition fails for $m,n=1$? Then we have $$|\left<m\right>/\left<nm\right>|=|\left<1\right>/\left<1\right>| = |\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z|=|\{e\}| = 1 = m$$ just as claimed.

Comment: Hint: $\langle n\rangle/\langle nm\rangle=\{0+\langle nm\rangle,n+\langle nm\rangle,2n+\langle nm\rangle,\dots,n(m-1)+\langle nm\rangle\}$.

Comment: If does fail if either $m$ or $n$ is $0$, though. (Except, by coincidence, for $(n,m)=(0,1)$).

Comment: If $n=1$, then $\langle n\rangle$ is not a *proper* subgroup, but it is still a subgroup.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Given the formulation of the exercise, I assumed that the proposition must fail for $m,n = 1$ which didn't make much sense to me. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the homomorphisms
\begin{align}
f\colon\langle n\rangle &\to \mathbb{Z} & g\colon\mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z}/\langle m\rangle \\
x&\mapsto x/n & x&\mapsto x+\langle m\rangle
\end{align}
What is the kernel of $g\circ f$? Then note that $g\circ f$ is surjective and apply the homomorphism theorem.

Actually there is no restriction about $m$ and $n$; they just need to be $\ge1$.